# XSL Retrieve child data

Tags: xml

I want to retrieve the data of the DESCRIPTION child.

My XML :

```
<RETURN type="object">
    <DESCRIPTION>...</DESCRIPTION>
</RETURN>
```

And i tried to retrive the data of **DESCRIPTION** like this, but it doesn't seems to work :

```
<xsl:for-each select="RETURN">
    <xsl:for-each select="DESCRIPTION">
        <DIV>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </DIV>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: try *<xsl:for-each select="RETURN/DESCRIPTION">*.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="RETURN">
<DIV>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./DESCRIPTION"/>
</DIV>
```